# uninitialized constant bigdecimal (nameerror)

Tags: ruby

```
val = BigDecimal.new("0")
```

Running this statement shows uninitialized constant bigdecimal (nameerror) error.

Then modifying to:

```
require "bigdecimal"
val = BigDecimal.new("0")
```

That's ok.
BigDecimal belongs to Ruby Standard Library. So I need to `require 'bigdecimal'`?

**Question:**

- Where is `BigDecimal` defined?
- What's the definition file? I didn't find the file in lib folder.

Answer (score 5):

Just because it's in the Ruby core doesn't mean it's automatically imported into your program. If it loaded everything it'd take forever to get Ruby started.

The correct way to do this is to use `require`. Why? It's only loaded if you need it.

The reason you can't find `bigdecimal.rb` is because it's written in C for performance reasons, so it's a library that's actually imported on-demand.

Comment: Even if it's written in C, there should be a file in the directory of `Ruby`.A text file or binary file.Maybe the file name is not `bigdecimal`, however what's it?[This link](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.5/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) shows it's defined in `bigdecimal/bigdecimal.c`. But I didn't find this file.

Comment: _"Just because it's in the Ruby core doesn't mean it's automatically imported"_ – this sounds confusing since "core" usually refers to the [Core API](http://ruby-doc.org/core/) whose classes _are_ automatically imported, as opposed to the [Standard Library API](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/) where `BigDecimal` comes from.

Comment: There is some room for better phrasing here. I say "core" as in the core libraries bundled with Ruby, but you're right, it's technically the Ruby Standard Library.

Answer (score 0):

As @tadman wrote: extensions are only loaded on demand in order to improve startup time/memory footprint.

You can find `BigDecimal` here

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/bigdecimal/bigdecimal.c and in some other places:

On GitHub it's easy to search a file. Just hit 't' and then type 'bigdecimal' and you see all files with this name.

Comment: Can't I find it in my local directory where I installed `Ruby`?

Comment: depends on how you installed ruby. What is wrong with the one on github?

Comment: No problem. I only want to find it in my local directory. I installed `Ruby` with RubyInstaller. [here](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)

Comment: Sorry, I don't use windows so can't be of much help.